# PHP convert MongoDB\BSON\Binary to base64

Tags: php, mongodb, base64, bson

I have jpeg files stored (in binary format) in a MongoDB and I would like to retrieve them in PHP and have them encoded in Base64 (so that I can provide the image as inline in HTML (`<img src="data:jpeg;base64," . base64_encode($imgData->getData()) . " />`).

Unfortunately the `base64_encode($imgData->getData())` generates the following exception:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class MongoDB\BSON\Binary could not
>   be converted to string in (...)

What would be the best approach to get the binary data encoded in base64?

Many thanks,
Tom

Comment: what `var_dump($imgData->getType());` returns?

Comment: It returns: int(0)

Comment: And var_dump($imgData->getData()) returns string(73843) (followed by unreadable binary data)